# How to iterate over this object

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
var navArray = {
  '#item1' : 0,
  '#item2' : 1,
  '#item3' : 2,
  '#item4' : 3,
  '#item5' : 4,
  '#item6' : 5
}
```

The ident var in the code below is a number and I need to find out which property it corresponds to in the array...so if ident is 1 I want to get #item2 back..

How do I do this?

```
var navArray = {
  '#item1' : 0,
  '#item2' : 1,
  '#item3' : 2,
  '#item4' : 3,
  '#item5' : 4,
  '#item6' : 5
}
if(typeof(ident) === "number") {
    for(i in navArray) {
    }
}
```

Comment: navArray[i] should do it

Comment: Your `navArray` isn't an array at all. Is there something wrong with using `navArray = ['#item1', '#item2', '#item3', ...]`? Then you'd be able to index into it directly: `navArray[ident]`.

Comment: @K Ivanov: your solution assumes that data is sorted. elduderino, is this object always the same so that sorting is a safe assumption?

Comment: It is important to note that this example is _not_ an array, but an object/map/associative-array (whatever you want to call it) - you can tell by the {} syntax - arrays use [].  Your variable name is confusing..

If you want to iterate an array, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/251185

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
var ident = 1,
    target = null;
for (var key in navArray) {
    if (navArray.hasOwnProperty(key)) { 
        if (navArray[key] === ident) {
            target = key;
            break;
        }
    }
}

alert (target); // "#item2"
```

Comment: In which case will this: `navArray.hasOwnProperty(key)` not return true??

Comment: @yankee: as per Crockford: "Be aware that members that are added to the prototype of the object will be included in the enumeration. It is wise to program defensively by using the hasOwnProperty method to distinguish the true members of the object."